# SQL Select last row from row that have same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am new to sql and went through alot of discussion and youtube but i get more confused.

I was using `SELECT * FROM tp_posts` to list number of posts into my website so basically below is how my table looks like.

```
          table name tp_posts
==========================================
|  ID       |       post   | tp_product
=================================================
|   1       |  toyota 1    | toyota
|   2       |  mercedez 1  | mercedez
|   3       |  bmw 1       | bmw
|   4       |  toyota 2    | toyota
|   5       |  toyota 3    | toyota
|   6       |  toyota 4    | toyota
==========================================
```

Above table is example on how it looks as you can see it will show all the i items above if i use the normal query i mentioned above so i started using this

```
SELECT * FROM tp_posts GROUP BY tp_product
```

`this works but it only shows the first toyota post and hide the latest ones and order by is not working also as group by hide the other posts`

I want to display the latest post while filtering related posts that share the same tp_product column, it has to show the last toyota post from above table

---

```
          table name tp_posts
========================================================
|  ID       |       post   | tp_product      post_numb
========================================================
|   1       |  toyota 1    | toyota        |   1
|   2       |  mercedez 1  | mercedez      |   1
|   3       |  bmw 1       | bmw           |   1
|   4       |  toyota 2    | toyota        |   2
|   5       |  toyota 3    | toyota        |   3
|   6       |  toyota 4    | toyota        |   4
==========================================
```

Update This is the complete table now as you can see above post section and post_num are related on post it shows toyota 1 tp_product which is product type = toyota and post_numb = 1 which represents toyota 1 in posts section.

Some people suggested i use order by but it doesn't work like that as i get all posts in table either way i want to get the result that look like this table below

```
table name tp_posts
========================================================
|  ID       |       post   | tp_product      post_numb
========================================================
|   6       |  toyota 4    | toyota        |   4
|   3       |  bmw 1       | bmw           |   1
|   2       |  mercedez 1  | mercedez      |   1

======================================================
```

I want to get The above results in my query, sorry if i was not clear enough Thanks

Comment: please share the result data you are expecting from above record set.

Comment: Do you have a date column or "latest" means highest id?

Comment: i have a number column for example above there in tp_product column we have 4 rows who share the same toyota value right? all of the have toyota 1, toyota 2, toyota 1 as values in the post section, i didn't include but there is another column that records the post section numbers i will update the question above.

Comment: @Qaiserdevs check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to generate row number partitioned by `tp_product` then order by `post_numb` descending; with consideration that the largest `post_numb` will be the "latest". Make that as subquery and do a `WHERE Rnum=1` to only return the ones being deemed as "latest":

```
SELECT ID, post, tp_product, post_numb
   FROM
(SELECT ID, post, tp_product, post_numb,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tp_product ORDER BY post_numb DESC) AS Rnum
    FROM tp_posts) v
    WHERE Rnum=1;
```

However, this only work with MySQL v8+ and MariaDB v10.2+.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=41944e78d6c3d53ebaf96abae42d56a4)

Comment: Thanks it worked, but am facing another issue right now. The query is taking alot of time like around 5 seconds because there is alot of records in the database about 500k

Answer (score 1):

if you always want to select last row then you can use below query

```
SELECT * FROM tp_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Else share the expected result from above data. Then only solution can be suggested.

Comment: This would have no relation to the car model. `while filtering related posts that share the same tp_product column`

Comment: I am still confused with the discussion. Unless the OP shares the expected result, I think no one can suggest

Comment: please check again i updated the question and added result table. i want to get content from table above where tp_product have same value show the last one ordered by post_numb desc

Comment: Last row ***per product***, not the last row in the whole table. Also known as greatest-n-per-group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, by using `MAX` to select the `max post_numb` for each `tp_product` inside a subquery, then sorting them in a descending order to achieve your desired result.

The subquery will select the `MAX post_numb` and the main query will get the row where the `post_numb` matches what was selected by the subquery according to `tp_product`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tp_posts a
WHERE post_numb = (SELECT MAX(post_numb) 
                   FROM tp_posts b 
                   WHERE a.`tp_product` = b.`tp_product`)
GROUP BY tp_product 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Result:

```
ID  post        tp_product  post_numb  
--  ----------  ----------  -----------
 6  toyota 4    toyota      4          
 3  bmw 1       bmw         1          
 2  mercedez 1  mercedez    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to SQL too, but
The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT(), MAX(), MIN(), SUM(), AVG()) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).